# Under what conditions minimax is equivalent to maximin?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Under what conditions $$ \min_{x} \max_{y} f(x,y) = \max_y \min_x f(x,y) $$ ?

Comment: Mahdi, welcome here. :-)

Comment: Is $f$ linear, are $x,y$ unconstrained?

Comment: no $f$ is not even convex. $y$ is integer. $x$ is a vector whose some of its elements are integers and the others are not constrained.

Comment: You should add that information into your post so that people needn't sift through the comments to find it. Use the `edit` button (or if you can't find it, follow [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/432365/edit)). Welcome to M.SE!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that there are some theorems called "Minimax Theorems" that says under what conditions this equality holds.

Comment: Yes, for example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theorem